# Is it possible to update the old build version numbers in the teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

I have a requirement that i need to update the build version numbers of old releases. Currently build version number starts with '1'. But i need to update to some number for old releases. I am using teamcity 7.1.5 (build 24400). Is this possible to update the old version number like 1.0.23568 to 5.0.23568?

Comment: I am pretty sure not. Maybe with a direct database operation but I can hardly recommend that.

Comment: Teamcity using HSQLDB internally, how can i update the database for new version numbers.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, especially if you have injected that version in to the build artifacts.

Comment: Mahesh, you really should not. If you must, please consult JetBrains (the vendor) for this would be an undocumented operation. [Here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Feedback) is a number of ways to get in touch with JetBrains.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the suggestion.